# Why the application is still running?

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I have an application that has a for, but if I close the window inside the loop, the loop continues to the last item before close the application. The code is this:

This is the code in my ViewModel:

```
private bool _estaCerrada = false;
public bool EstaCerrada
{
    get { return _estaCerrada; }
    set
    {
        _estaCerrada = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("EstaCerrada");
    }
}


for(int i = 0; i< 2; i++)
{
    EstaCerrada = true;
}
```

This is my View:

```
<Window x:Class="MiAplicaion.Login"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:miAplicacion.Behaviors"
        Name="ucPrincipal"
        Behaviors:WindowCloseBehavior.IsClose="{Binding EstaCerrada}">
```

And this is my attached property that allows me to close the window from the ViewModel:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;


namespace GTS.CMMS.Client.Behaviors
{
    public class WindowCloseBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCloseProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
            (
                "IsClose",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(WindowCloseBehavior),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsClosePropertyChanged)
            );


        public static bool GetIsClose(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsCloseProperty);
        }
        public static void SetIsClose(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsCloseProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnIsClosePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if(miVentana != null)
            {
                if((bool)args.NewValue)
                {
                    miVentana.DataContext = null;
                    miVentana.Close();
                }//((bool)args.NewValue)
            }//(miVentana != null)
        }//OnIsClosePropertyChanged
    }//class WindowCloseBehavior
}
```

The code works in the way that I can close the window and the application from my ViewModel when I set the property EstaCerrada to true.

My problem is that I don't know why, in the loop, it has to iterate 2 times when the application should be close in the first iteration.

I could solve the problem adding a break after set EstaCerada to true, but I would like to know why the application still is working when I close the windows and alse I set to null the DataContext of the view.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have 2 window instances?

Comment: Did you set a break point in `OnIsClosePropertyChanged` and debugged the code? Just a guess, but I think `RaisePropertyChanged` just _posts_ a message that is handled when the UI thread has time again. While your `for` loop is running, there is no time to handle that event.